# How to clean everything (preferences DB etc) everytime a debug session starts in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to do a complete cleanup everytime I start a debug session with eclipse on android. Just like a complete wipe off of my package (data + apk + any preferences)

Comment: When you "start" a debug session? Probably not, since you can launch the debugger at any point when you're application is running. What's your end goal?

Comment: There are 2 methods a) start a fresh debug session in which the apk is installed -- I see installing apk in Console. (b) attach to a process which is what you are mentioning. I am looking for (a) so that I dont need to have the baggage of old preferences DB which I just fixed in code.